# Matlab will not use flat shading, defaults to faceted

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Hopefully a simple question: I have a matlab script that uses the contourfm function. I have explicitly told it to use flat shading, however it keeps defaulting back to faceted shading. Any ideas why? The code is below. 
Thanks.

```
h = figure;
axesm('eqdcylin','maplonlimit',[0 360],'maplatlimit',[0 90]);
contourm(gLat, gLon, meanh', 16,'Color',[0.05 0.05 0.05],'LineWidth',2);
hold on
contourfm(gLat, gLon, varh', 30); 
shading flat;
lm=worldlo('POline');
   for i=1:length(lm);
      lm(i).otherproperty = {'color','m','LineWidth',2};
   end
displaym(lm);
gridm on;
tightmap;
set(h, 'Position', [1 1 1400 700]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The shading property does not apply to `contourm` and `contourfm`. If you do not want the lines between the different colour regions, add `'LineStyle', 'none'` in the parameters of your `contourfm` function:

```
contourfm(gLat, gLon, varh', 30 , 'LineStyle', 'none' );
```

and you can delete or comment your call to `shading flat;`